# What transmission can I join to a 2JZ GTE to support 600 bhp in a Lexus IS300?

Tags: transmission, performance, lexus

I've been researching various transmissions that are popular to connect to a *built* 2JZ GTE engine. It looks like a popular choice is a [Magna PT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_PT) V160 6-speed manual. However, I'd like to know if there are other well known and used options.

Are there alternatives that can really take the 600bhp without needing to be rebuilt multiple times?

Here's what I'm looking for more specifically:

- 6-speed
- Manual
- Power tolerance
- *Fittable* in an IS300 (if the tunnel needs altered a bit that's fine)

Comment: Cheap ones **will** break - do the job properly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm waffling on this question, because while you ask "what fits", you are really asking us a shopping question to get recommendations as to what will work for your needs. Shopping questions are off-topic for the site. I'll leave this up to the site (for now), but realistically it is my thought this should be closed as such.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for the feedback! Would you have any recommendations for narrowing this down to site goals that would somehow preserve my own? Even slightly? :)

Comment: I'm not really sure. It seems to me what you're asking is better served by you looking at specs and figuring it out based on your goals, rather than us giving you 2nd hand advice. The biggest portion is not HP ratings, but torque ratings, especially with a standard shift transmission. The GETRAG (now Magna PT) transmissions, even in stock form, were very good transmissions (well, most of them) for holding power/torque, far in excess of their stated limits. Rebuilt ones with cryo'd gears, Kevlar synchros, and metal fork pads are probably your best.bet.

Comment: It might be worth popping into [chat] and seeing if anyone has any suggestions?